# tikzpicture dynamically calculate points

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm learning how to draw diagrams with `tikzpicture` and I am looking for some help to dynamically calculate some points. I've made the diagram below, but I am struggling to calculate the point U^* `(0,-4)` and `(6, -4)` dynamically. Along with the definition of the arcs at `(0:45:2)` and at `(0:-34:2)`. My initial inspiration was this [diagram](https://thetarzan.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/tikz-diagrams-for-economists-an-excise-tax/). MWE below

[image: diagram]

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.22]
\coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
\coordinate (gs) at (12,12);
\coordinate (gi11) at (0,4);
\coordinate (gi12) at (12,8);
\coordinate (u) at (12,-8);

\scriptsize
% Draw the axis
\draw[help lines,->] (origo) -- (12,0) node  (raxis)  [right] {$r$};
\draw[help lines,->] (origo) -- (0,12) node  (gaxis)  [above] {$g$};
\draw[help lines,->] (origo) -- (0,-12) node  (uaxis)  [below] {$u$};

% Draw the two intersecting lines of g^s and g^i
\draw(origo) coordinate (gs_1) -- (gs) coordinate (gs_2)  node[right]{$g^s$};
\draw(gi11) coordinate (gi_1) node[left, font=\tiny]{}--(gi12) coordinate (gi_2) node[above right]{$g^i$};
% Draw u
\draw(origo) coordinate (u_1)--(u) coordinate (u_1) node[above right]{$u$};

% Calculate the intersection of the lines gi_1--gi_2 and gs_1--gs_2% and store the coordinate in c.
\coordinate (c) at (intersection of gi_1--gi_2 and gs_1--gs_2);

% Draw dashed equilibrium line
\draw[gray, dashed] (0,-4) node[left] {$u^{*}$}--(6, -4) coordinate--(c |- raxis)   node[below right] {$r^{*}$}--(c |- c)--(gaxis |- c) node[left]{$g^{*}$}; 

% Draw arc and label
\draw (0,0) ++(0:2) arc(0:45:2); % that the 45 is dynamically created 
\node [right, font=\tiny] at (1.5,1.1) {$s_\pi$};
\draw (0,0) ++(0:2) arc(0:-34:2); % that the -34 is dynamically created 
\node [right, font=\tiny] at (1.5,-.8) {$\frac{v}{\pi}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the intersection I used the syntax of the `intersections` library instead of the old syntax you use. Your version still works, but I don't think it's documented in the manual.

I draw a path down from `c` and calculate the intersection of this and the `u` line to help in drawing the dashed line.

To draw the angles I use the `angle` `pic` from the `angles` library, and the `quotes` syntax from the library of the same name.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.22]
\coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
\coordinate (gs) at (12,12);
\coordinate (gi11) at (0,4);
\coordinate (gi12) at (12,8);
\coordinate (u) at (12,-8);

\scriptsize
% Draw the axis
\draw[help lines,->] (origo) -- (12,0) node  (raxis)  [right] {$r$};
\draw[help lines,->] (origo) -- (0,12) node  (gaxis)  [above] {$g$};
\draw[help lines,->] (origo) -- (0,-12) node  (uaxis)  [below] {$u$};

% Draw the two intersecting lines of g^s and g^i
\draw [name path=gs] (origo) -- (gs) node[right]{$g^s$};
\draw [name path=gi] (gi11) -- (gi12) node[above right]{$g^i$};

% Draw u
\draw [name path=u] (origo) -- (u) node[above right] {$u$};

% Calculate the intersection of the lines gi_1--gi_2 and gs_1--gs_2% and store the coordinate in c.
\path [name intersections={of=gs and gi}] (intersection-1) coordinate (c);
\path [name path=downfromc] (c) -- (c|-uaxis) coordinate (belowc);
\path [name intersections={of=downfromc and u}] (intersection-1) coordinate (c2);

% Draw dashed equilibrium line
\draw [gray,dashed] (c-|origo) node[left]{$g^{*}$} -| (c2) -- (c2-|origo) node[left] {$u^{*}$};
\node [below right,gray] at (origo -| c)  {$r^{*}$};

% Draw arc and label
\pic [draw,"$s_\pi$"{font=\tiny,shift={(1.2em,.5em)}}] {angle=raxis--origo--gs};
\pic [draw,"$\frac{v}{\pi}$"{font=\tiny,shift={(1.2em,-.4em)}}] {angle=u--origo--raxis};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## A slight variation

Saving the dimensions of the axes in macros, so it's easier to change.

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\EFyext}{12*0.22}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\EFxext}{\EFyext*1.2}
\coordinate (origo) at (0,0);
\coordinate (gs) at (\EFxext,\EFyext);
\coordinate (gi11) at (0,\EFyext/3);
\coordinate (gi12) at (\EFxext,\EFyext*2/3);
\coordinate (u) at (\EFxext,-\EFyext*2/3);

% Draw the axis
\draw[help lines,->] (origo) -- (\EFxext,0) node  (raxis)  [right] {$r$};
\draw[help lines,<->] (0,-\EFyext) node (uaxis)  [below] {$u$} -- (0,\EFyext) node  (gaxis)  [above] {$g$};

% Draw the two intersecting lines of g^s and g^i
\draw [name path=gs] (origo) -- (gs) node[right]{$g^s$};
\draw [name path=gi] (gi11) -- (gi12) node[above right]{$g^i$};

% Draw u
\draw [name path=u] (origo) -- (u) node[above right] {$u$};

% Calculate the intersection of the lines gi_1--gi_2 and gs_1--gs_2% and store the coordinate in c.
\path [name intersections={of=gs and gi}] (intersection-1) coordinate (c);

% calculate 
\path [name path=downfromc] (c) -- (c|-uaxis) coordinate (belowc);
\path [name intersections={of=downfromc and u}] (intersection-1) coordinate (c2);

% Draw dashed equilibrium line
\draw [gray,dashed] (c-|origo) node[left]{$g^{*}$} -| (c2) -- (c2-|origo) node[left] {$u^{*}$};
\node [below right,gray] at (origo -| c)  {$r^{*}$};

% Draw arc and label
\pic [draw,"$s_\pi$"{font=\tiny,shift={(1.2em,.5em)}}] {angle=raxis--origo--gs};
\pic [draw,"$\frac{v}{\pi}$"{font=\tiny,shift={(1.2em,-.4em)}}] {angle=u--origo--raxis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I tried running your code changing the angle of u by changing `\coordinate (u) at (12,-8);` to `\coordinate (u) at (12,-10);` when it failed to draw the `[gray,dashed]` I tried fixing it by changing `0,-10`, but got stuck again with your new code. Could you possible give me a hint to solve this?

Comment: @EricFail I modified that part a bit, drawing the line down from `c` to the y-level of `uaxis`. Works for `u` down to about `(12,-25)`.

Comment: Thanks, super helpful. What's with the _slight variation_ version? I don't understand what you did there and why. You did however answer my question!

Comment: @EricFail The difference is just that the lengths of the axes (and some other things) are all calculated based on one macro. Perhaps not a big deal here, but if you have numbers that are repeated a lot in a drawing then saving those to a macro makes it easier to change an image, as you don't have to modify every occurrence of the value, you just change the definition of the macro.